# Linking library build with ndk r10 into project build with ndk r13 using c++_shared stl

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk, ndk-build

We have a prebuild library that was build with android ndk r10e. The Project we are working on is being build with ndk r13b. When trying to link the library our build fails with undefined reference errors for all functions of the library containing ndk stl provided classes such as strings. The error:

```
Foo.cpp:39: undefined reference to `namespaceFoo::Bar::fooBar(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

we fixed this issue with another library by just building it with ndk 13 as well. Unfortunately for one of the necessary libraries it is out of our control.

We link the c++_shared lib as stl.

Is there a way to make this work? Can we somehow correctly link the library build with ndk r10?

EDIT: Making clear that we use the c++_shared stl. This seems to be the underlaying issue.

Comment: I do not think that the problem is in the linking part. are crosscompiling with cmake? gradle? your architectures? I use ndk10e and ndk13b and I have no problems. But your problems could come with the std and stl standar functions because android NDK is trying to add stl features to support c++11 string features such as (strof).

Comment: both builds are currently using gcc toolchains. Are you using c++_shared as stl? When checking inside the ndk the c++_shared was changed a lot between these NDK versions. I think that that is the actual underlaying issues. It happens for all arm architectures (not sure about x86).

Comment: I usually use gnustl_static in my cmake android properties, because it is by default in the toolchain file.

Comment: This seems to confirm my suspicion that the underlaying issue is a change to the c++_shared stl.

Comment: I recommend you to try to use CrystaX NDK if you are going to use stl and std features, and it supports C++17 experimental. https://www.crystax.net/. Maybe in your future developments you will avoid these issues.

Comment: unfortunately we have to build a complex 3rd party library and are limited by which NDK versions they support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been ages since I asked this.

It turns out google has been doing a lot of work on the c++_shared lib and the NDK itself resulting in these incompatibilities. We never ran into anything this critical with later NDK's again.

TL/DR: Yes they where incompatible.